# Gino + SQLAlchecmy + Postgres How reload model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiohttp, gino

Now i use

```
# Get user
usr = await UserModel.get(1)
# some updates like 
await UserModel.update.values(name="Test").apply()
# then i need reload usr
usr = await usr.get(usr.id)
```

But i think that bad way :-(
May be some one know better way to reload model instance?